# appropriate verb for and as a conjunction?

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

Rule for subject verb agreement.
My grammar book states that " If two subjects are joined by **and** then the verb comes in plural form" for instance" John and Matt are coming."
But in another sentence I read " He and not his parents is plead guilty to obscenity charge." here the verb agrees with the subject former to 'and'.
Is this an exception?

Comment: ***not** his parents* - that negates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*He and not his parents is plead guilty to obscenity charge* is not grammatical; maybe it should be *is to plead* or *has plead*. Whatever the case, it should be obvious that there is a singular subject (he) that takes a singular verb. The sentence itself rules out another subject by saying *and not - - - -*. Therefore doesn't it make sense that the verb should be singular? The first sentence could be *John and not Matt  is coming*. Note that John is the only one coming so the verb is singular.

Comment: Is "**John and Matt are coming.**"  grammatically wrong? my book says it correct one.

Comment: To see that the *not* sentence is singular, we can show it this way: He (and not his parents) is pleading" or "He, and not his parents, is pleading."

Comment: @Boris *John **and** Matt are coming* is grammatical. *John and not Matt **is** coming* is grammatical. But not *John and not Matt are coming*.